# Is it possible to add ref of props.children have no ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here an example...

`App.js`

```
<Wrapper>
        <p ref={React.createRef()}>{state.result2}</p>
        <p>{state.result2}</p>
        <p>{state.result3}</p>
        <p>{state.result4}</p>
</Wrapper>
```

**`Wrapper.js`**

```
{props.children.map((child, idx) => (
        <ChildItem
          key={idx}
          {...props}
          child={child}
        ></ChildItem>
))}

 {props.children}
```

And be able to do some logic in **`ChildItem.js`** using the **element ref** without passing it in every element from `App.js`.

EX, I want to change the background of any element after some logic check
So, I can change `props.child.ref.current.style.background = '#fff';`

**NOTE: I don't want to add any ref from `App.js`**

**If there is any way to manipulate the props.children or clone and then add ref this solution is Ok for me**

Any hint?

Comment: That's for directly possible. You might looking for this https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: I don't want to add any ref from `App.js`

Comment: Why would you do something like this with reference? Not only you got styling solutions, you also have advanced API in react like cloneElement.

Comment: I may try to cloneElement of the whole props.children and manipulate it.

Comment: I'm working on a Wrapper Component that can highlight every change in its children, but it is a must for me to pass a ref on every child to be able to highlight it.
Passing that ref on every element is very annoying and I want to create it from the wrapper.

here is a demo.
http://react-change-highlight.surge.sh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Wrapper extends Component {
  render () {
    const { children } = this.props
    const childrenWithRefs = React.Children.map(children, child => {
      // use child.props here ...

      return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: React.createRef() })
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {childrenWithRefs}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) and making a styled `p` that can take props. This way you can change the styles using conditions.

```js
const Paragraph = styled.p`
  background-color: ${props => props.someVar === 'someValue' ? '#fff' : '#000'};
`
```

Comment: I want to manipulate it from the `Wrapper.js` not from the `App.js`